# Convert keysym names to keycodes

Tags: c, linux, x11, keycode, xcb

How would I convert (what I think are) keysym names (Return, space, A, ...) to keycodes?

I am trying to make something a bit like sxhkd/xbindkeys, where they are read from a config file.

I've got other parts going with XCB. Can I do this with XCB?

Comment: Did you look at: [link](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/keyboard/) KeySym to KeyCode doc?

Comment: I'd like to add/emphasize that `XKeysymToString` from that link does not require a `Display*`, but only the keysym. So, this can also be used with XCB. Alternatively, one would have to get the underlying lookup table from somewhere else, which does not seem to be worth the trouble.